# How can I make "Max Mega Menu" work on my custom theme?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, megamenu

I was wondering if any of you could help my with this. I've download & install the plugin **Max Mega Menu** but nothing appear. I follow each of their step on the plugin docs but what ever I do my menu stay the same. The plugin is suppose to overright wordpress' default setting ( which in my case is not true ) and it seems like I'm the only one with this problem since every issues I saw is for customization problem ( responsive, more buttons, etc ).

**EDIT**

Forgot to update my post. My problem seems to be resolved. Can't remember exactly what it was be I think it had something to do with the way I used wp_nav_menu.

Comment: I would suggest to post it [here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/megamenu) and author will help you in this. This plugin is having really nice support.You can see its review as well.

Comment: It's the first thing I did. Been 3 or 4 days since I post my problem there and no one have help me yet.

Comment: Author maybe have not seen your post. Bump and check your luck ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully configured Max Mega Menu [at this site](http://rojgar.saurabdulal.com.np/), please follow the steps below to configure in your website

1. Download the plugin and/or install it from you WP-Dashboard

   Go to **Dashboard->Appearance->Editor->header.php** and find following line of code with `'theme_location' => 'primary'`
2. Replacing primary menu **php** with Max Mega Menu **php**

   Comment this line `<?php ..'theme_location' => 'primary'....?>` and paste 
   `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>` exactly at the same position
3. Now go to **Dashboard->Appearance->Max Mega Menu Settings** (at the
   left side of Dashboard) and click the enable button
    [image]

**Voila**!!  you too have successfully configured Max Mega Menu in your WP-Theme

**Note:-** Please do not forget to flush the cache or simply you can reload your page with http://www.yourwebsite.com?=anything and get fresh one

For more information on how to configure **Max Mega Menu** please have to look at [this documentation](http://www.maxmegamenu.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/)

Comment: Thanks but my problem seems to be fix now. Can't remember what I did but I think it was something far too obvious like select the menu as primary (kinda like what you did at #2) or something missing in the code (function in #2). Anyway thanks for trying to help me. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for back then :P

Answer (score 1):

Is your `<head>` session width the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` tag? 
If it's not, i think this will fix your problem.